# .htaccess rewrite alphanumeric subdir

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite (alPHa numeric including . and - symbols)

```
http://domain.tld/alP.Ha1-23
```

to

```
http://domain.tld/?~/az/forsaj/alP.Ha1-23
```

How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ /?~/az/forsaj/$1 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: hi. this works, but I want only alpha numeric, . and - symbol

Comment: i am converting it to nginx syntax and its not worked there. i did it this way
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)$ /?~/az/forsaj/$1 [L,QSA,NE]

Comment: Sorry I don't know nginx syntax good enough to give a precise answer.